# Docker: Restricting inbound and outbound traffic using iptables

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, docker, haproxy

We have lot of applications that run on Linux server using Docker.

As an example, let us say my application runs on **ServerA** as a container (Docker).

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES

df68695a00f1        app/myapp:latest   "/run.sh"           2 weeks ago         Up 2 days           0.0.0.0:50423->3000/tcp   reallymyapp
```

The app is listening on the port 50423 on the host (mapped to port 3000 on the container).

The DNS (endpoint) that is used to access the app is pointing to the HAProxy host (say **ServerB**), that routes the traffic to **ServerA:50423**.

Everything works well so far.

The security team in our org raised a concern that all external source IPs are potentially allowed to connect to such Docker hosts (like **ServerA**) and they want us to restrict traffic to allow only a specific IP (**ServerB** which is a load balancer) to access the containers and vice versa (**ServerA** to **ServerB**). We would then allow connectivity from our users' machines to **ServerB**/load balancer only.

Now, I followed Docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/) and tried to insert the following rule using iptables to DOCKER-USER chain:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i ekf192 -s 10.1.2.10, 10.1.2.11, 10.1.2.12 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i ekf192 -j DROP


ACCEPT     all  --  10.1.2.10  anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  10.1.2.11  anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  10.1.2.12  anywhere
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level info prefix "IPTables Dropped: "
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Please note that we need both incoming and outgoing traffic from/to these hosts (10.1.2.10, 10.1.2.11, 10.1.2.12).

Now, as per my (limited) knowledge on iptables, these rules should drop all incoming requests except for when it is origination from the mentioned IP addresses and vice versa i.e. allow outgoing traffic to mentioned IPs.

The incoming traffic works as expected but the outgoing traffic to these HOSTS is getting dropped.

I am scratching my head over this and cannot figure out what is going wrong...and not to mention that I absolutely suck at understanding how iptables rules work.

```
Jan 12 16:24:43 sms100394 kernel: IPTables Dropped: IN=docker0 OUT=ekf192 MAC=02:42:09:37:a0:14:02:42:ac:11:00:02:08:00 SRC=172.17.0.2 DST=10.1.2.10 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=40235 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=3000 DPT=42579 WINDOW=242 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0
Jan 12 16:24:44 sms100394 kernel: IPTables Dropped: IN=docker0 OUT=ekf192 MAC=02:42:09:37:a0:14:02:42:ac:11:00:02:08:00 SRC=172.17.0.2 DST=10.1.2.11 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=3000 DPT=45182 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
Jan 12 16:24:45 sms100394 kernel: IPTables Dropped: IN=docker0 OUT=ekf192 MAC=02:42:09:37:a0:14:02:42:ac:11:00:02:08:00 SRC=172.17.0.2 DST=10.1.2.12 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=3000 DPT=45182 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
```

Answer (score 0):

iptables doesn't know about "flows" by default, only about individual packets. So for outgoing packages a separate rule needs to be added, something like:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i ekf192 -d 10.1.2.10, 10.1.2.11, 10.1.2.12
```